# Stretch background image for UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage, textures

I got texture, which really shorter, than my UIButton.

I got this texture:

[image]

And i should create this button:

[image]

How should i stretch (not tile), this texture? Stretching in horizontal direction

Thnx

Answer (score 70, accepted):

From the example images you provided I'm pretty sure you're looking for `UIImage`'s [`resizableImageWithCapInsets:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets:)

```
UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right);
UIImage *stretchableImage = [originalImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:insets];
[myButton setBackgroundImage:stretchableImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
// the image will be stretched to fill the button, if you resize it.
```

The values in the UIEdgeInsets struct determine the margins you don't want to be stretched. Your left and right values could be about this wide:

[image]

The top and bottom values can be either 0 (if you don't want to resize the button vertically), or probably half of the total height.

Comment: resizableImageWithCapInsets available in iOS 5.0 and later. do you know somethinf for iOS 4.3?

Comment: Probably not the answer you wanted, but the last estimate I saw was that 90% of all iPhones are running at least iOS 5.0. iOS6 already had 30% penetration after 8 days. Just sayin', you might consider changing your target rather than trying to shoe-horn a solution into 4.3.

Comment: @drummerb You should be using `setBackgroundImage:forState` instead of `setImage:forState`.

Comment: Here's a little tool I wrote that might help: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/thecapper

Comment: This created some of the strangest behaviors I've ever seen.

Answer (score 38):

With Xcode 6 (and **iOS7+** target) you can use slicing editor when working with images assets.
Toggle slicing mode with **Editor -> Show Slicing** menu or press **Show Slicing** button when select specific image with editor (showed below).

[image: Show Slicing button]

Then you can select image for specific display scale and drag rules or edit insets values manually.

[image: Rules]

After that you can select this image in *Interface Builder* for *UIButton* **Background Image** (IB button's representation could look bad, but it should be OK when running).

My buttons look well (running iOS 7.1 simulator and iOS 8 device).

[image]

This Apple doc [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/SlicinganImage.html) could be helpful.

Comment: Just curious, even after slicing you still need to set the content insets of your UIButton right?

Comment: @DanielGalasko no need to set the content inset. For me just slicing did the job.

Comment: Don't get fooled by interface builder! It works with running app.

Answer (score 3):

By not tiling, I assume you can thus not use

```
- (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets
```

The way to do what you want is to use:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0); // should be proportionally larger
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextDrawImage(context, (CGRect){{0,0}, newSize}, [yourImage CGImage]);
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;
```

Comment: Well, you sort of changed your question after I responded, so @DrummerB provided the answer I would have given you, but then he gave you a really nice image of how to define the caps! I just gave him a +1 primarily for the image that shows you exactly how to do it!

Answer (score 1):

Use `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:` method.

Refer: https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/StretchableImages

Comment: deprecated for `resizableImageWithCapInsets:`

Answer (score 1):

Or using **Stretchable Images**:

```
UIImage* imgbkg =[[UIImage imageNamed: @"my_bkg_image.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:10];

[_button setBackgroundImage: imgbkg forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Use **0** if you don't want to stretch certain side.

Comment: deprecated for `resizableImageWithCapInsets:`

Comment: @Cœur is it really deprecated? I always use this because it is simpler.

Comment: deprecated since iOS5. But if you still support iOS4, the old way is still supported even with iOS9.