# How can I animate the resizing of a button without affecting its border?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, resize, cgaffinetransform

On iOS7, I need to generate an animation of a button which grows laterally (on one side only). To achieve this effect I tried a combination of scaling and translation, but the problem is that scaling affects the size of the border as well, which is not something I want.

In this example, after doubling the length of the button, the side borders double their width as well:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
[[button layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];
[[button layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];

[UIView beginAnimations:@"button" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

button.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat( CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2,1), CGAffineTransformTranslate(button.transform, 50, 0));

button.alpha = 1.0f;
[UIView commitAnimations];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

I wonder if there is a clever solution to achieve this effect without using CGAffine transformations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can animate the `borderWidth` of the button with other properties, it's animatable. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right);
UIImage *stretchableImage = [originalImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:insets];
[myButton setBackgroundImage:stretchableImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
// the image will be stretched to fill the button, if you resize it.
```

> The values in the UIEdgeInsets struct determine the margins you don't
>   want to be stretched.

answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623961/stretch-background-image-for-uibutton)