# Action Sheet Button text alignment

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

I am using actionsheet, and I have added unicode symbol. But my button title is not centered. I want the unicode symbol to be located at right most. If you think that it is impossible, can I use flag image separately rather than using unicode symbol ? If yes, how could I add image next to the button title?

```
UIActionSheet *actionsheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Would you like to see ozone cloud in your area or a trace of your walking/driving/biking activity" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OzoneMap",@"ParticleMap", @"TraceMap      \U0001F6A9", nil];

[[[actionsheet valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:0] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

[image]

Comment: It is centered. Show the code for creating the button with the Unicode character in the name.

Comment: It's doing just what you told it to. What's the problem? The button's title is centered. Keep in mind that the title includes all of the spaces and the flag character.

Comment: I want the flag to be right most.

Comment: You can't - not at least with `UIActionSheet`.

Comment: Can I use flag image separately rather than using unicode symbol ?

Comment: People don't expect the flag to be at the rightmost. There's a reason everything is centered in `UIActionSheet`.

Comment: Can I add image next to the button ?

Comment: OT For the button background image use `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` to maintain the outline shape. See this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12625066/451475)

Comment: How could I add background image on action sheet? Please also check my updated code to add image. When I add image, then it does not show title anymore.

Comment: It is possible, look at WhatsApp... Can't find any solution to that..