# Using UIAlertController How do I add an image on the right side of UIAlertAction Text?

Tags: swift, xcode, customization, uialertcontroller

Yes I am Aware that I can add images using this code. And I've tried playing with it.

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
action.setValue(UIImage(named: "someImage.png"), forKey: "image")
alertController.addAction(action)
view.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Which would result to an alert controller looking like this.

[image]

took the image from this post [How can i customize UIAlertAction in UIAlertController for iOS8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29226050/how-can-i-customize-uialertaction-in-uialertcontroller-for-ios8)

[image]

like on this post [Action Sheet Button text alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24293544/action-sheet-button-text-alignment), but UIAlertActionSheet is deprecated and Swift docs says that I should use UIAlertController now.

I've also read this post [UIAlertController custom font, size, color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460706/uialertcontroller-custom-font-size-color)

and seeing the first answer

```
// this has to be set after presenting the alert, otherwise the internal property __representer is nil
guard let label = action.valueForKey("__representer")?.valueForKey("label") as? UILabel else { return }
label.attributedText = attributedText
```

this code can only be executed after the alert has been presented. But I need to add the image before presenting the alert controller. any idea guys?